# Get rendered text letters dimensions

Tags: c#, silverlight, textblock

I've got a really simple setup - I have a `string`, a font and a font size on the ready. I want to render this to a Silverlight `WriteableBitmap`.

There's one catch - I want to be able to tell apart the letters in the rendered text. Ideally, I'd like to have a `System.Windows.Rect` for every rendered letter.

The problem is Silverlight's API, which is missing all of the useful stuff like [`Graphics.MeasureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx), which I could have used to measure the letters separately.

What adequate options do I have to get the letters' measures in codebehind?

Comment: What about getting the Font.Size? This should give you the em size of the font and then you could calculate from there?

Comment: @Pseudonym: that wouldn't get me the letters' width (which can also be different for every letter: the font is not monospace)

Comment: I have a really bad way to do this, but it would get the job done, how many letters will you be processing?

Comment: @Pseudonym: not much, 2-3 words on average. It's going to vary with different cases

Comment: Okay, you could throw each individual letter into an unstyled textbox and then get the length of that property

Comment: @Pseudonym: how can I get the width/height of an unstyled textblock in codebehind without rendering it to the visual tree? Can you give an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76097/discussion-between-pseudonym-and-mints97).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured this out on my own. The solution is slow and far from perfect, but hey, it works!

The idea is to render the text many times, adding one letter at a time, and finding the difference between the current and previous `TextBlock` widths.

So, for example, if the text is `"ab"`, we first render `"a"` and get its length. Then we render `"ab"` and find the difference, which should be the size of the rendered `"b"`.